# Module Import error - cannot find module

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was trying to import the module dynamically in ES6 on Meteor application. But getting an error **cannot find module**. The same import works when I'm using the static import statement.

Please have a look at the below code -

```
const JOBS = ['update-report-cron'];

const jobs = {
  start() {
    JOBS.forEach((job) => {
      console.log(`job ${job} has been started`);
      let fileName = './' + job + '.js';
      console.log(require(fileName));
    })    
  } 
};

module.exports = {jobs};
```

**ERROR - Cannot find module './update-report-cron.js'**

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
export default const jobs = {
  // your code
}
```

When you import, use

```
import { jobs } from './update-report-cron.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ru's answer is not correct, not sure how it's your answer.

Try

```
export default const jobs = {
  // your code
}
```

When you import, use

```
import jobs from './update-report-cron.js'
```